# UWP AutoSuggestBox получение данных из коллекци

Tags: c#, uwp

Имеется класс из которого хочу получить значения `Name` для вывода в поисковой блок `AutoSuggestBox`.

```
namespace App_GiftDB
{
    public class Items
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ImgPath { get; set; }
        public string ContentPath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Заполняю `ObservableCollection`, затем пытаюсь сделать поиск:

```
ObservableCollection<Items> Gifts;
Gifts = App.repo.GetItems(item, "");


private void FilterEditText_OnTextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.CheckCurrent())
    {
        var term = FilterEditText.Text.ToLower();
        var results = Gifts.Where(i => i.Name.ToLower().Contains(term)).ToList();
        FilterEditText.ItemsSource = results; 
    }
}
```

В итоге получаю такой вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как выводить список из названий?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее `TextMemberPath="Name"` должен решить вашу проблему.

Почитать про [`AutoSuggestBox.TextMemberPath`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.autosuggestbox#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_AutoSuggestBox_TextMemberPath).